# sqlite database unique column with a counter

Tags: android, android-sqlite

[image: screen shot showing a new user screen]

So i have an app which collects user's data and creates an account for each user.It also has a meter's list where,when each user enters an apartment for instance,they are assigned a meter number from the meter's list and another property is an account number e.g user no.1 will be '0001-01'.

When this user moves out of the apartment,and someone else moves into the same apartment,the account number would be the same but the last part should change-increase by 1 e.g '0001-02'.So this tells me that,the new tenant is the n'th user of that apartment number 1.Another tenant moving into a different room would have a number like '0002-01',and another room would be '0003-01' and so on.How would i go about implementing this part?So far i just have an edit text field and i just type in a random number.There isn't much validation or functionality there.

Screen shot below